# Hibernate :Dynamic hibernate column creation

Tags: hibernate

How can I create dynamic columns in already existed tables(based on user selection) in database through hibernate mappings?

can you please suggest any topics to proceed this.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : [www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields](http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields)